# How to make VSCode snippets that trigger only in double quote

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to create a small VSCode plugin that has autocomplete function for the Bootstrap classes.

I would like this autocomplete to work **only** when the cursor is between double quotation marks.
[image]

Is it possible to restrict the display of the auto-complete list only for this range?

I tried something like this:

```
"BTN": {
    "scope": "string.quoted.double.html",
    "prefix": "work-btn",
    "body": [
        "test-class;",
    ],
    "description": "BS4"
}
```

but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to use syntax scopes in a snippet, see the discussion at

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/71187

I was going to suggest upvoting that issue but it has been locked.  The functionality seems like it would be useful for various reasons, but might be cpu-intensive.